# Trigger to sum in values in an SQL database column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

I have a database with 2 tables in SQL Server 2008 Express.

My problem is the following: I would like to create a trigger to sum some values in first table and copy the sum into second one.

For example the first table (`Head`) has 5 columns :

```
  ID    Transaction    Acount    Date        Total_sum
  -----------------------------------------------------
   1    some text      acount1   2014.04.15   300
   2    some text      acount2   2014.04.15   500
   3    some text      acount1   2014.04.15   200
```

And the second table `Transaction`:

```
 HeadID    Amount    Remarks
 ----------------------------
    1       100        test1
    1       200        test2
    2       500        test3
    3       100        test3
    3       100        test4
```

So finally I would like to sum the values in `Transaction` if they have the same `HeadID` and copy the result into the `Head` table.Maybe Could I find the last ID in the 'Head' table and group HeadID-s in the 'Transaction' table and sum the values

Please help me!

Comment: Your DBMS is Sql Server or MySql?

Comment: Ohh sorry MySql server 2008 express

Comment: Er... on one hand there is MySQL from Oracle, and on the other hand there's an SQL Server 2008 express from Microsoft. I assume you mean the latter?

Comment: Removed MySql tag. Dear poster, please at leat try to read the name of the product you use. MySql Server 2008 Express would be a new invention. It does not exist. If you can not bother to put any work into your questions, why should we bother to answer them?

Comment: What have you tried, outside of dumping the problem to us withoug showing any effort? Where do you fail?

Comment: At least try the simple JOIN query before the trigger.

Comment: How large are the tables?  Why do you need a trigger for this operation, which can be accomplished more easily using a query?

Comment: I would use an indexed view to store the sums, if storing the sums is indeed necessary. SQL Server already knows how to keep indexed views maintained so that they remain consistent with the base tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I understood that you need to create a trigger on 'transaction' table. When ever a record is inserted/updated/deleted to/in/from 'transaction' table, you want the latest sum against each 'headid' to be updated to 'Head' table. If so, try the below else put some more information on your problem..

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Transaction]
   ON  [dbo].[Transaction]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Head SET Total_Sum=(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM dbo.[Transaction] WHERE Head.Id=[Transaction].HeadId GROUP BY HeadId)
END
GO
```

I have assumed that you already have an entry in 'Head' before inserting/deleteing/modifying records in 'Transaction'

If I am missing something, please let me know.

Comment: That works.  If transaction has many rows it may be better to reference the INSERTED and DELETED tables instead of the base table and write differences to Header.  The OP's underlying architecture is poor, however; the application should be handling this.

Comment: Thanks your idea was the way :)

Comment: I have tried this query.And it works pretty well if in the Head table exist only one ID.So how to sum values if in the Head table already exist not only 1 ID. Maybe could I group HeadId by last ID(in Head table)